# single param yul for loop

Tags: solidity, yul

I am trying to understand this for loop pattern:

```
                for {
                    // Shift n right by 1 before looping to halve it.
                    n := shr(1, n)
                } n {
                    // Shift n right by 1 each iteration to halve it.
                    n := shr(1, n)
                } { ... }
```

I guess it can be translated into

```
for(uint256 n = n/2; n > 0; n = n/2) { ... }

OR 

for(n >> 1; n > 0; n >> 1) { ... }
```

Is that correct ? I'm mainly concerned with the stop (middle) parameter but maybe even other parameters are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved. I'm pretty sure this is correct now as I can now get the desired result I was looking for.